# Do Palestinian territories actually contain any prisons or similar penal/detention facilities?

Tags: palestine, gaza, prison, hamas

Hamas has made homosexuality punishable by 10 years imprisonment, but does it actually maintain/administer/have access to any prison facilities in the first place? If so, how many, and what are they called?

Comment: HRW has [a 2012 report on abuses in Gaza's judicial system](https://www.hrw.org/report/2012/10/03/abusive-system/failures-criminal-justice-gaza). Hamas is clearly detaining accused and convicted criminals, but I'm not sure how much detail you will find.in there about exactly where.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Searching Google Maps with **gaza strip prison** returns [this](https://www.google.com/maps/place/%D8%B3%D8%AC%D9%86+%D8%A7%D8%B5%D8%AF%D8%A7%D8%A1+%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%B1%D9%83%D8%B2%D9%8A%E2%80%AD/@31.3639647,34.2978063,17z/data=!4m14!1m7!3m6!1s0x14fd9122faaedd15:0x643e5ba4cf4c5e2!2z2LPYrNmGINin2LXYr9in2KEg2KfZhNmF2LHZg9iy2Yo!8m2!3d31.3639647!4d34.3003812!16s%2Fg%2F11svln2h0x!3m5!1s0x14fd9122faaedd15:0x643e5ba4cf4c5e2!8m2!3d31.3639647!4d34.3003812!16s%2Fg%2F11svln2h0x?entry=ttu) place in Khan Yunis, marked as سجن اصداء المركزي, *Asdaa Central Prison, 9872+H5J, Khan Yunis, Gaza Strip*.

Goggle finds an [article](https://web.archive.org/web/20230421194315/https://www.hjc.gov.ps/ar/%D8%B5%D9%84%D8%AD-%D8%AE%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%8A%D9%88%D9%86%D8%B3-%D8%AA%D8%AA%D9%81%D9%82%D8%AF-%D8%A3%D9%88%D8%B6%D8%A7%D8%B9-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%86%D8%B2%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%A1-%D9%81%D9%8A-%D8%B3%D8%AC%D9%86/) about that prison from the domain hjc.gov.ps, which seems to be the one used by the Hamas government. Due to the war situation, the site seems to be unreachable, therefore I have linked to `web.archive.org`.

It starts (from arab by Google Translate)

> Khan Yunis Magistrate inspects the conditions of inmates in Khan Yunis Central Prison
>
> Gaza - Supreme Judicial Council
>
> Counselor Ahmed Sheikh Khalil, President of the Khan Yunis Magistrate Court, conducted an inspection tour of the Correction and Rehabilitation Center in Khan Yunis, “Asdaa’ Central Prison.” ...

Answer (score 5):

A [gay man who fled from Gaza](https://www.i24news.tv/en/news/middle-east/palestinian-territories/1660138495-exclusive-gay-man-who-fled-gaza-speaks-about-experience-with-hamas) mentioned a small room where he was imprisoned for three days, though it's unclear if it's a dedicated facility or just a spare room. An [activist](https://apnews.com/article/israel-middle-east-coronavirus-pandemic-marriage-gaza-strip-1836eabe150e816658907967835f029a) experienced three different facilities, an interrogation room handling multiple prisoners for days, a tiny cell holding him for months, and a "central prison" for long term inmate.

So yes, they *do* have access to buildings they use as prisons, but it's unclear if they always use such buildings for all cases (the gay man is only imprisoned for short terms, and doesn't seem to actually have any court sessions).

Answer (score 2):

Amnesty International reports of a Katiba Prison in Gaza City ([link](https://www.amnesty.org/en/latest/news/2015/05/gaza-palestinians-tortured-summarily-killed-by-hamas-forces-during-2014-conflict/)):

> "Ibrahim Dabour, an insurance company employee and father of two
> children, was held at **Katiba Prison in Gaza City** standing trial
> before a military court on a charge of “communicating with hostile
> sides” when he was taken out and extrajudicially executed by firing
> squad on 22 August 2014.
>
> “We were told about the execution by people around us at 1pm. There
> was no official notification. He was executed at 9:30am on Friday. My
> brother received a text message at 10:31pm that night saying ‘The
> judgement against Ibrahim Dabour has been carried out according to the
> Shari’a as per the ruling of the Revolutionary Court’,” his brother
> told Amnesty International.

The same article also mentions lengthy prison sentences and torture, which probably also requires a prison / detention canter:

> Atta Najjar, a former police officer under the Palestinian Authority
> who has a mental disability, was serving a 15-year prison term imposed
> by a military court after he was arrested in 2009 and subsequently
> convicted of “collaborating” with Israel. On 22 August 2014, he was
> taken out from the prison and executed.
>
> “There were marks of torture and bullet shots on his body. His arms
> and legs were broken… his body was as if you’d put it in a bag and
> smashed it… His body was riddled with about 30 bullets. He had
> slaughter marks around his neck, marks of knives… And from behind the
> head – there was no brain. Empty… It was difficult for us to carry
> him… He was heavy, like when you put meat in a bag; no bones. His
> bones were smashed. They broke him in the prison,” said his brother,
> who retrieved the body from al-Shifa hospital morgue on 22 August
> 2014.
>
> Eight detainees were still on trial charged with “collaboration” with
> Israel at the time of their executions. Six others had been awaiting
> the outcome of appeals against death sentences from a military court
> in Gaza on the same charges. Two others had been convicted and were
> serving prison terms when they were executed. Many had been sentenced
> after trials before courts whose proceedings are grossly unfair. A
> number had said they had been tortured in order to extract
> “confessions”.